# How to avoid optimistic concurrency error for newly added record in EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, optimistic-concurrency

I use Entity Framework 6 in an MVC 5 project an there is an entity relations between Experiment and FileAttachment (one Experiment can gave many FileAttachment). During Edit an Experiment record, I load a ViewModel containing both of the entities and list the attachments under the experiment in edit mode:

The scenario is as explained below:

1) There is a Delete button for each FileAttachment and when user delete an attachment, it is deleted via AJAX and display an information message on the same modal window.

2) But, if the user add a new attachment after deleting an attachment and save the Experiment the following error is encountered:

> "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded."

- I think the reason is that: 
  I load Experiment and FileAttachment entities and then I change the FileAttachment entity by deleting a record. But there is still the same entity loaded first time and I want to save the outdated entity. So, maybe I need to create an entity and fill it before saving, but `context.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Added,` 
  `context.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Modified` and `context.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Unchanged` does not make any sense. What should I do to **simply attach the newly added FileAttachment to the database**?

**Models:**

```
public class Experiment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties 
    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}



public class FileAttachment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ExperimentId { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string FileMimeType { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties 
    public virtual Experiment Experiment { get; set; }
}
```

***ViewModel:***

```
public class ExperimentViewModel
{
    //code omitted for brevity

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public JsonResult Update([Bind(Exclude = null)] ExperimentViewModel model)
{
    List<FileAttachment> fa = new List<FileAttachment>();
    //code omitted for brevity (At this step I add all the attachments in the model to "fa" paarmeter)

    //Mapping ViewModel to Entity Model (ExperimentViewModel > Experiment) :::::::::::::::::
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ExperimentViewModel, Experiment>();
    });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    //var source = new ExperimentViewModel();
    var dest = mapper.Map<ExperimentViewModel, Experiment>(model);
    ////::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    repository.SaveExperimentWithAttachment(dest, fa);
}
```

***Concrete:***

```
public void SaveExperimentWithAttachment(Experiment experiment, IEnumerable<FileAttachment> fileAttachment)
{ 

    //Update Block 
    using (var context = new EFDbContext())
    {
        context.Entry(experiment).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (FileAttachment f in fileAttachment)
        {
            context.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a view model, not you data models in the view, and posting back the view model. You then get the data model in the POST method and update its properties from the view model and save.

Comment: What if you get the *live* `Experiment` entity from the context, then clear its `FileAttacments` collection then add those in `IEnumerable<FileAttachment> fileAttachment`? (`experiment.FileAttachments.Clear(); experiment.FileAttachments.AddRange(fileAttachment);`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I use ViewModel and post it to the Controller. Then I map it to Entity Model and then send it to SaveExperimentWithAttachment() method. So, at which step should I bind the properties to the entity model? Now I map it in teh Controller, but I think I should create a new entity instance and bind the data coming from View. Then add it to the entity. Any idea?

Comment: You need to give a bit more information. What are your view model(s) and the the controller method. And why are you saving each `FileAttachment` - you have previously deleted those you do not want, and so all you need to do is add the new ones

Comment: @haim Do you mean like that in the Update section? Could you post as answer pls?

Comment: @ClintEastwood, Your updated code doesn't seem to fetch the live entity from the context. You need something like `var liveExp = context.Experiments.Find(experiment.Id)` then `liveExp.FileAttachments.Clear()` then `foreach ... liveExp.FileAttachments.Add(fileAttachment)`

Comment: @haim I updated the method as shown Update2 but still the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Try to get rid of all those `context.Entry(...)` statements. Aside from that, does `SaveExperimentWithAttachment` gets called before the delete attachment (ajax) request is done?

Comment: @haim Thanks a lot for your help. If it is possible could you please post the code you mentioned as answer so that not missing any point?

Comment: Does it work? If yes, I will

Comment: @haim Please look at Update 3.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the necessary code to my question. As I said in the scenario, I retrieve an Experiment record having 1 FileAttachment and add 1 file to this edited record using File Upload. Then I encounter problem.

Comment: Does `List<FileAttachment>` contain only the files you have uploaded? And you don't need `liveExp.FileAttachments.Clear();` all you need to do is add the new `FileAttachment` objects based on what the use has uploaded because your not modifying any existing `FileAttachment`.

Comment: And the issue could be with your `mapper`. I suggest you just try manually updating the `Experiment` data model from the view model properties as a test.

Comment: But I have already used the mapping approach for many other pages in the project. The problem is shortly is that: I get a Experiment records having 1 file using ExperimentViewModel. Then I upload one file more and then send it to the database. **As editing a file attechemnt is not possible and I have to remove or add file attachment** I must say EF that FileAttachment entity is Added while Experiment is modified. I think the problem will be solved if I can say EF that... Is that true?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Finally I changed my method as shown Update 4. I think that is a true approach to set EntityState.**Modified** for Experiment and EntityState.**Added** for FileAttachment. But this time I encountered **"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.FileAttachment_dbo.Experiment_ExperimentId\". The conflict occurred in database \"Laboratory\", table \"dbo.Experiment\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."**

Comment: @haim770 Finally I changed my method as shown Update 4. I think that is a true approach to set EntityState.**Modified** for Experiment and EntityState.**Added** for FileAttachment. But this time I encountered **"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.FileAttachment_dbo.Experiment_ExperimentId\". The conflict occurred in database \"Laboratory\", table \"dbo.Experiment\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."**

Comment: Have you set the value of `ExperimentId` in the new `FileAttachment`? (you still have not shown your models!)

Comment: Get the live entity from the context (all inside one single `using`) and avoid all `Entry()` calls.

Comment: @StephenMuecke **You rock!..** Yesss, I forgot to update the **ExperimentId** in each FileAttachment. Many thanks for your effort and help... I also add the final answer so that other people can also benefit from your help... Regards...

Comment: @haim770 Many thanks for your help... The problem has been solved and I also add the final answer. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer by fixing the problems with the help of **@StephenMuecke** and **@haim770**. Many thanks both of you for your effort and kind help... Regards.

```
public void SaveExperimentWithAttachment(Experiment experiment, IEnumerable<FileAttachment> fileAttachment)
{
    using (var context = new EFDbContext())
    {
        context.Entry(experiment).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (FileAttachment f in fileAttachment)
        {
            // !!! I forgot to update the ExperimentId field for each file attachment
            f.ExperimentId = experiment.Id;
            context.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Added; //Because file attachment(s) is not updated, newly ADDED
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```